# Is it possible to restrict generic types when overloading in Java without casting?

Tags: java, generics

I have a generic class `C<T>` that defines a method `doStuff(T arg)`. I want to define a subclass S that restructs the access to `doStuff`, let's take the example where it has to be a `Number`. I've come this far:

```
public class C<T> {

    public void doStuff(T arg) {}

}

public class S<T extends Number> extends C<T> {

    public void doStuff(T arg) {
        Number n = (Number) arg;
    }

}
```

This means, however, that I have to cast `T` to `Number` in my `S` method. Is there an elegant way to avoid this?

Thanks!

Comment: There is no need to cast: http://ideone.com/AWu5Xi.

Comment: I've rolled this question back.  While I can appreciate that you may believe that what you had before was a follow-up question, it wasn't; it was a conceptually different thing to be asking.  I strongly encourage you to ask a new question around it instead, as you run the risk of invalidating existing answers to your previous question by adding it here.

Comment: understandable, new question asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, a couple of things:

- `C<T>` is unbound.
- `S<T extends Number>` is bound to `Number` and its children classes.

So, in effect, you've accomplished what you want to do.  The casting is unnecessary since `T` in `S` is already bound to `Number`.

To extrapolate it a bit further, if you created other subclasses of **`C<T>`** in which you defined the bounds on `T`...

`public class Q<T extends Date> extends C<T>`

`public class R<T extends Collection> extends C<T>`

...all of these classes would have their `T` bound by whatever's on the right of the `extends` clause.

Comment: Thanks! In this case, how can I return a Number? I've edited my question to include this.

Comment: I feel that you should be asking a new question.  What you've asked before and what you're asking now are now conceptually different.

Answer (score 1):

Since `T` is a subclass of `Number` anyway, you do not have to cast at all. For your example:

```
public class C<T> {

public void doStuff(T arg) {}

}

public class S<T extends Number> extends C<T> {

    public void doStuff(T arg) {
        System.out.println(arg instanceof Number);
    }

}
```

`doStuff()` would always return true then (except `arg` equals `null`).

Answer (score 0):

**You can completely remove the casting.**

If it would not work, the generics would be very weak feature.